# IotHubException: Put token failed. status-code: 500

Tags: azure, exception, azure-storage, azure-iot-hub

I am running c# application that sends telemetry messages from devices to iot-hub account in azure portal.

while running the service, I have received the following error.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Exceptions.IotHubException: Put token failed. status-code: 500, status-description: Unable to retrieve AMQP Artifacts for iothub.xxx-iothub.173358.6eb6f09e/14c2bb95-0ea1-4fe4-86c6-xxxxxxx. Timeout: 00:00:45..
   at Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Transport.AmqpTransportHandler.<SendAmqpMessageAsync>d__27.MoveNext()
```

Can anyone please clarify me the meaning of this error?

Comment: Which tutorial do you follow or can you show your code?